# How to print out to standard output a boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, ipv4

I am running the c++11 chat example from boost.asio examples and trying to print out the tcp::v4() return value to see what ip address the server is using. There is no to_string function that works on boost::asio::ip::tcp as it does on boost::asio::ip.

Here is the main function from the server.cpp of the chat example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc < 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: chat_server <port> [<port> ...]\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    std::list<chat_server> servers;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), std::atoi(argv[i]));
      servers.emplace_back(io_context, endpoint);
    }

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no to_string function that works on boost::asio::ip::tcp as it does on boost::asio::ip

That's confused. `boost::asio::ip::tcp` is a class that you never instantiate (it's a static class modelling a protocol), `boost::asio::ip` is a namespace, you can't expect to print a namespace.

Then, there's a lot of irrelevant code in your sample. Let's for the sake of it assume your chat_server was the one trying to print the end-points:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b63495edb2f24b39)**

```
struct chat_server {
    chat_server(boost::asio::io_context&, tcp::endpoint ep) {
        std::cout << "Serving on " << ep << "\n";
    }
};
```

Prints something like

```
Serving on 0.0.0.0:100
Serving on 0.0.0.0:110
Serving on 0.0.0.0:120
...
```

If you really want to take the question title literal, you'd print the address part of the endpoint:

```
    std::cout << "Serving on " << ep.address() << "\n";
```

Which prints the slightly useless

```
Serving on 0.0.0.0
Serving on 0.0.0.0
Serving on 0.0.0.0
...
```

That's because you didn't bind to an interface. Slightly more useful if you do:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1578a7dc6ad086c5)**

```
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(ip::address_v4::loopback(), std::atoi(argv[i]));
```

```
Serving on 127.0.0.1
Serving on 127.0.0.1
Serving on 127.0.0.1
```

### TL;DR

All the code you needed:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::asio::ip::address_v4::loopback() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: My question was confused indeed but you shed some light on this for me. Thank you.